# What do I put under content-type in my header using php?

Tags: php

I have been using PHP for some time and I am trying to standardize my pages in terms of what they serve such as: text/html or json or possibly serving a file.

What I don't understand, when setting headers, is the "content-type" variable.

Is it possible to set MULTIPLE things with "content-type" or does "content-type" exclusely refer to the MIME type you are setting for the page?

Here is what I am currently setting but I don't know if there is anything else I should set with it:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json');
?>
```

This may sound "novice" but would help.

Thank you.

Comment: in general you let the server do its thing - so to answer you need to provide a specific example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-type is specified per page, and you can and should set only one per page.

It tells the browser what type of page or request it's receiving so it knows how to render the output.

[w3 - Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17)

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `content-type` header you are telling the browser which MIME type to treat the following output as. You would use this if, for example, your PHP was not generating an HTML output but instead an image or audio file.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a Content-Type?**
A "Content-type" is simply a header defined in many protocols, such as HTTP, that makes use of MIME types to specify the nature of the file currently being handled.
**What is a MIME type?**
MIME stands for "Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions. It's a way of identifying files on the Internet according to their nature and format. For example, using the "Content-type" header value defined in a HTTP response, the browser can open the file with the proper extension/plugin.
Source: [MIME Types List](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Comment: if your going to copy and past from another, you need to cite the source

Comment: You didn't answer the question he asked: Is it possible to set MULTIPLE things?

Comment: @Barmar I did? "makes use of MIME types to specify the nature of the file currently being handled" and "the browser can open the file with the proper extension/plugin". Seems pretty self explanatory to me. I could be wrong, but if you start setting multiple MIME types the browser wouldn't know which to use?